# I am using angular 13 to emit custom event. But my event emitter is not fired.Kindly let me know the reason behind it

Tags: angular, events, custom-events

The below is the code of the child component, post-create and parent component, app component. I am using angular 13 and running it in the Ubuntu operating system. I want to emit a custom event when a button specified in the child component is clicked executing the function specified in the parent component when that event is emitted. It seems that the event is not triggered.

---

**Child component**
**Html**

```
<mat-card>
   <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Enter Post Title</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" 
      [(ngModel)]="titlevalue">
   </mat-form-field>
   <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Enter Post Content</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput rows="5" [ 
      (ngModel)]="contentvalue"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
</mat-card>
<button color="accent" mat-raised-button 
(click)="onAddPost()">Save Post</button>
```

**Child component TS file**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output} from 
'@angular/core';

import {Post} from '../post.model'
@Component({
    selector: 'post-create',
    templateUrl:'./post-create.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./post-create.component.css']

})

export class postcreatecomponent {


   titlevalue: any;
   contentvalue: any;
   @Output()
   posted: EventEmitter<Post>=new EventEmitter<Post> 
   ();
   onAddPost(){
     const post:Post={
     title:this.titlevalue,
     content:this.contentvalue
   };
   this.posted.emit(post);

 }

}
```

**Parent HTML file**

```
<header></header>
<main>
    <post-create (posted)="onPostAdded($event)"> 
    </post-create>
    <output-post [posts]="storedPosts" ></output- 
    post>

</main>
```

**Parent TS file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from './posts/post.model';
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
  storedPosts:Post[]=[]
  onPostAdded(post:Post){
  this.storedPosts.push(post);

  }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is it failing?, have you checked by console.log(), which events are firing and which are not.

Comment: The custom event posted is not getting emitted. The method onAddPost() is getting executed but the method onPostAdded() is not getting executed.

Comment: I got the error solved, actually I had included child component in the bootstrap in main app. It got working once I removed it.